# Reset local variables of metrics after each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, metrics

I use the built-in method [tf.metrics.precision](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/precision) to evaluate my model. I was looking through its [definition](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py), but the local variables are never reset.

Shouldn't they be reset after each epoch in order to remove the counts from the last epochs? Is this done automatically and I was just overlooking it in the source code, or am I supposed to do it? If the latter is true, how do I reset the local variables? I didn't read anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: You can check this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50138424/10530728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables for keeping track of metrics are created with the [`metric_variable`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/metrics_impl.py#L41-L51) function and thus added to the collection with key [`tf.GraphKeys.METRIC_VARIABLES`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys#METRIC_VARIABLES). After you have defined all your metrics, you can have a reset operation like this:

```
reset_metrics_op = tf.variables_initializer(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.METRIC_VARIABLES))
```

And run it after each epoch is finished.

Comment: I had something like this in my mind, but couldn't find anything in the documentation. They should add a note about this!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One must be careful how to reset variables when processing the data in batches. Arranging the operations while calculating overall metrics (i.e., precision, accuracy or auc) and batch metrics is different. One needs to reset the running variables to zero before calculating accuracy values of each new batch of data.

With `tf.metrics.precision` , two running variables are created and placed into the computational graph: `true_positives` and `false_positives`. So, you can choose which variables to reset using `scope` argument of `tf.get_collection()`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

labels = np.array([[1,1,1,0],
                   [1,1,1,0],
                   [1,1,1,0],
                   [1,1,1,0]], dtype=np.uint8)

predictions = np.array([[1,0,0,0],
                        [1,1,0,0],
                        [1,1,1,0],
                        [0,1,1,1]], dtype=np.uint8)

precision, update_op = tf.metrics.precision(labels, predictions, name = 'precision')

print(precision)
#Tensor("precision/value:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
print(update_op)
#Tensor("precision/update_op:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)

tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES)
#[<tf.Variable 'precision/true_positives/count:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>,
# <tf.Variable 'precision/false_positives/count:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>,

running_vars_precision = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES, scope='precision')
running_vars_auc_initializer = tf.variables_initializer(var_list=running_vars_precision )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(running_vars_auc_initializer)
    print("tf precision/update_op: {}".format(sess.run([precision, update_op])))
    #tf precision/update_op: [0.8888889, 0.8888889]
    print("tf precision: {}".format(sess.run(precision)))
    #tf precision: 0.8888888955116272
```